# reload grid when click on button and filter grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I add some buttons in the top of my grid that shows orders statuses.
https://pasteboard.co/I5lM7c8.png

I want send parameter to Magento grid to filter and reload the grid

for example, when I click completed orders button, it should be list completed orders in the grid.

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('my_model')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

I can't get url parametrs in the block to fitter collection

is there any way to filter magento gird from outside the grid